# High swapiness on VM host

Tags: virtual-machine, swap

Would setting very high swappiness so that more RAM could be assigned to VM impact performance? I would assume that VM related tasks wouldnt be swapped, and the tasks within the VM.

Comment: [Setting `swappiness` to high values doesn’t free memory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/493436/86440), it tells the kernel to preserve the page cache as far as possible.