# Debug out-of-memory with /var/log/messages

Tags: linux, logs, memory, out-of-memory

The following report is thrown in my messages log:

```
kernel: Out of memory: Kill process 9163 (mysqld) score 511 or sacrifice child
kernel: Killed process 9163, UID 27, (mysqld) total-vm:2457368kB, anon-rss:816780kB, file-rss:4kB
```

Doesn't matter if this problem is for `httpd`, `mysqld` or `postfix` but I am curious how can I continue debugging the problem.

How can I get more info about why the PID 9163 is killed and I am not sure if linux keeps history for the terminated PIDs somewhere.

If this occur in your message log file how you will troubleshoot this issue step by step?

```
# free -m

             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1655        934        721          0         10         52
-/+ buffers/cache:        871        784
Swap:          109          6        103`
```

Comment: what all messages about the problem show up in `dmesg` ?

Comment: Useful details about OOM - https://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The kernel will have logged a bunch of stuff before this happened, but most of it will probably not be in `/var/log/messages`, depending on how your `(r)syslogd` is configured.  Try:

```
grep oom /var/log/*
grep total_vm /var/log/*
```

The former should show up a bunch of times and the latter in only one or two places.  That is the file you want to look at.

Find the original "Out of memory" line in one of the files that also contains `total_vm`.  Thirty second to a minute (could be more, could be less) before that line you'll find something like:

```
kernel: foobar invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
```

You should also find a table somewhere between that line and the "Out of memory" line with headers like this:

```
[ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes swapents oom_score_adj name
```

This may not tell you much more than you already know, but the fields are:

- **pid** The process ID.
- **uid** User ID.
- **tgid** Thread group ID.
- **total_vm** Virtual memory use (in 4 kB pages)
- **rss** Resident memory use (in 4 kB pages)
- **nr_ptes** Page table entries
- **swapents** Swap entries
- **oom_score_adj** Usually 0; a lower number indicates the process will be less likely to die when the OOM killer is invoked.

You can mostly ignore `nr_ptes` and `swapents` although I believe these are factors in determining who gets killed.  This is not necessarily the process using the most memory, but it very likely is.  For more about the selection process, [see here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92525/can-linux-run-out-of-ram/92544#92544).  Basically, the process that ends up with the highest oom score is killed -- that's the "score" reported on the "Out of memory" line; unfortunately the other scores aren't reported but that table provides some clues in terms of factors.

Again, this probably won't do much more than illuminate the obvious: the system ran out of memory and `mysqld` was choosen to die *because killing it would release the most resources*.  This does not necessary mean `mysqld` is doing anything wrong.  You can look at the table to see if anything else went way out of line at the time, but there may not be any clear culprit: the system can run out of memory simply because you misjudged or misconfigured the running processes.

Comment: `dmesg` is where this is guaranteed to be. It'll only be in `/var/log` if the syslog daemon reads from `/dev/kmsg` (which it usually does though).

Comment: @Patrick That depends on *when* you go to look.  If it's recorded in one of the normal file logs (it should be, or you have done something stupid with your logger), it will be there for a long time, whereas by this point, if the OP wants to diagnose a problem that occurred yesterday, or the day before, etc., the record may not be in `dmesg` anymore even if the system was left running.

Answer (score 6):

The key to this is in the message itself - *Out of memory*. When the Linux kernel is starved of virtual memory (physical RAM plus swap) it will start killing processes and that's exactly what's happened here. It looks like `mysqld` was using over 2GB of virtual memory.

How much RAM and swap does the system have? I'd consider adding extra RAM or, if that's not possible, adding extra swap. As a quick fix to at least prevent processes from being terminated you could add a swap file.

**Update:** Looking at the amount of RAM you have, you can immediately see the problem. You have ~1.6GB of RAM and 100MB of swap yet MySQL is using a lot more RAM than that. That explains why you are seeing processes being terminated.

Comment: `total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1655        934        721          0         10         52

-/+ buffers/cache:        871        784
Swap:          109          6        103`


this is memory output at same time when the process was killed

Comment: Can you perhaps paste that in the original message, with formatting retained? Would make it easier to read.

Comment: I am not really good in formatting... but already paste it in the original message