# How to make OOM killer log into /var/log/messages when it kills any process?

Tags: linux, out-of-memory

I use CentOS 7 with kernel 3.1.0

I know there is a hitman in Linux called oom killer which kills a process that uses too much memory out of available space.

I want to configure it to log the activities so that I can check whether it happens or not. How can I set it up?

Thanks,

Comment: Last I checked the OOM killer was not shy about spamming the system logs with logs...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OOMkiller's activities are guaranteed to be in `/var/log/dmesg` (at least for a time).  Usually the system logger daemon will also put it in `/var/log/messages` by default on most distributions with which I've worked.

These commands might be of help in tracking the logs down:

```
grep oom /var/log/*
grep total_vm /var/log/*
```

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128667/20246%20This%20answer) has more details about parsing those log entries to see exactly what is going on.

Comment: Ran the above two commands and nothing appeared. But my java application was killed by OS. I am using centos server.

Comment: Yeah, CentOS doesn't seem to put it in `/var/log/dmesg` here either.  And unfortunately I don't have access to `/var/log/messages` on this system to check that (owned/only accessible by root).

Comment: Be careful with grep in those dirs it sometimes dies with `grep: memory exhausted` for me :)