# Executing a "fork bomb" safely

Tags: linux, shell, cgroups

We've all seen the "fork bomb" that will render a host non-responsive, even if executed in an unprivileged shell:

**Warning: Do not execute the following shell script. Just don't.**

```
:(){ :|:& };:
```

I'm also aware of [cgroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups), the Linux kernel-level process grouping structure that can assign "controllers" to limit memory, CPU consumption, I/O scheduling priority, etc.

Theoretically, it should be possible to use this control mechanism to allow a user to execute a fork bomb in their own shell without it bringing the host system to a crawl.

Since I'm not really aware of *how* a fork bomb consumes resources, I'm not sure how to use cgroups to do this.

Comment: On a BSD machine (at least OpenBSD/MirBSD), this is mostly safe, except as root: `ulimit`s are in place that prevent a user from spawning more than 128 processes. You’ll just need some help from root to kill them afterwards.

Comment: You might be interested in footnote #5 here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92525/can-linux-run-out-of-ram/92544#92544

Answer (score 5):

As far as I'm concerned, I think `cgroups` would be overkill here. However, I tend to use `ulimit` whenever I run something witk a `fork` system call in it (bad experiences made it a habit...) :

```
$ ulimit -u 2500
$ ./mypotentiallydeadlyprogram
```

This way, I put a 2500 processes limit on my current shell. Thanks to this, my `fork` calls will end up failing if they get too numerous, hence preventing the system from going down, and allowing me to furiously hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

On my machine, I find 2500 to be a good limit, but you might want to increase/decrease this value according to what your machine can take, and how far you want your fork bomb to go. **Also remember that your machine needs to spawn things to survive, don't suffocate it.** *I have seen people writing this in their `~/.bashrc`, therefore restricting even their session's main bash. While this was very funny to the sysadmin, the user was very unhappy to freeze after login.*

While `ulimit` can be used to set up a temporary limit, you can set something more permanent if you have root access (and want to enforce the limit on specific users). This can be done through `/etc/security/limits.conf`:

```
# <domain>      <type>      <item>      <value>
youruser        soft        nproc       2500
youruser        hard        nproc       2750
```

In the above setup, `youruser` has got a soft limit of 2500 processes (max. 2750). This file allows you to set up various kinds of limits, for various entities on your system (users, groups, ...). Have a look at [its documentation if you need more information](http://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf). Note however that this is system-wide configuration, which means that this limit isn't applied *per-shell* for `youruser`.

By the way, `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max` will contain the maximum PID which can be granted by your kernel. Since PIDs are reusable, you may consider this really close from your *maximum number of processes*.