# Infinite loop one liner for pen testing

Tags: bash, ssh

A bunch of years back I found this one line of bash script that basically would overload a linux system.

All I can remember is that it looked something like this and had the pipe (_(:;){:()|:()});

Now obviously the above code does not work, but hopefully someone has seen something like this similar in the past.

I used to have it written down somewhere, but alas I have lost that as well.

I'm testing my companies new SSH service and we're trying to break it. I'm hoping that something old school and simple may just do the trick.

Speaking of breaking into SSH. If anyone has any suggestions or there own 1 to 5 line ssh breakers that they'd like to share. Please don't hesitate.

The goal is to stop one from breaking out of the chrooted ssh environment.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **Standard disclaimer: The code below will likely bring your system to its knees.  Run only in a test environment and not a production environment, unless you are absolutely sure you have adequate protection.**

I assume you're looking for something like the classic "[fork bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb)":

```
:(){ :|:& };:
```

More info [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167795/executing-a-fork-bomb-safely) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159491/why-did-the-command-make-my-system-lag-so-badly-i-had-to-reboot).

Comment: Ah yes. The fork bomb. I forgot what it was called. Yput sir are awesome!